Describing the hook part of the symmetric group algebra
Let $\mathbf{k}$ be a field of characteristic $0$. Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and
consider the symmetric group $S_{n}$ consisting of all permutations of
$\left[  n\right]  :=\left\{  1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  $. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be
the group algebra $\mathbf{k}\left[  S_{n}\right]  $ of this group.
It is well-known that $\mathcal{A}$ can be decomposed as a direct product as
follows (the Artin--Wedderburn decomposition for $S_{n}$): For each partition
$\lambda$ of $n$, there is an idempotent $\overline{\mathbf{E}}_{\lambda}$ in
the center of $\mathcal{A}$, which can be defined by
\begin{align*}
\overline{\mathbf{E}}_{\lambda}=\dfrac{1}{\left(  h^{\lambda}\right)  ^{2}}
\sum\limits_{\substack{T\text{ is a tableau}\\\text{of shape }\lambda
}}\mathbf{E}_{T}=\dfrac{1}{h^{\lambda}}\sum\limits_{w\in S_{n}}\chi_{\lambda
}\left(  w\right)  w
\end{align*}
(where $\mathbf{E}_{T}$ is the Young symmetrizer of the tableau $T$, where
$h^{\lambda}$ is the product of all hook lengths of $\lambda$, and where
$\chi_{\lambda}$ is the irreducible character of $S_{n}$ corresponding to
$\lambda$). The left ideals $\mathcal{A}\overline{\mathbf{E}}_{\lambda}$ for
all $\lambda\vdash n$ are two-sided ideals and thus nonunital subalgebras
(though each one has a unity), and they are linearly disjoint, and their sum
is $\mathcal{A}$. Hence, $\mathcal{A}$ decomposes as a direct product
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{A}=\prod\limits_{\lambda\vdash n}\mathcal{A}\overline{\mathbf{E}
}_{\lambda}
\label{eq.darij1.1}
\tag{1}
\end{equation}
of these algebras. As algebra, each
$\mathcal{A}\overline{\mathbf{E}}_{\lambda}$ is isomorphic to the
endomorphism ring of the $\lambda$-Specht
module, thus to a matrix ring $\mathbf{k}^{f^{\lambda}\times f^{\lambda}}$,
where $f^{\lambda}$ is the number of standard Young tableaux of shape
$\lambda$.
Now we can play the following game: Pick a subset $U$ of the set of all
partitions of $n$, and consider the subproduct $\prod\limits_{\lambda\in
U}\mathcal{A}\overline{\mathbf{E}}_{\lambda}$ of the above direct product
\eqref{eq.darij1.1}. This is a nonunital subalgebra of $\mathcal{A}$, and will
be denoted by $\mathcal{A}_{U}$. Can we describe it more explicitly, without
using the $\overline{\mathbf{E}}_{\lambda}$'s? Can we find a simple set of
elements that generates $\mathcal{A}_{U}$ as a left (or right) ideal of
$\mathcal{A}$ ?
Sometimes the answer is yes:

If $U$ is the set of all partitions of $n$ having length $\leq k$ (for a
given integer $k$), then $\mathcal{A}_{U}$ is the span of the "row-to-row
sums" $\nabla_{\mathbf{B},\mathbf{A}}$ corresponding to all pairs of ordered
set partitions $\mathbf{A}=\left(  A_{1},A_{2},\ldots,A_{\ell}\right)  $ and
$\mathbf{B}=\left(  B_{1},B_{2},\ldots,B_{\ell}\right)  $ of $\left[
n\right]  $ with $\ell\leq k$. These sums are defined by $\nabla
_{\mathbf{B},\mathbf{A}}=\sum\limits_{\substack{w \in S_n ; \\w\left(  A_{i}\right)
=B_{i}\text{ for all }i\in\left[  \ell\right]  }}w$.

If $U$ is the set of all partitions of $n$ having length $>k$ (for a given
integer $k$), then $\mathcal{A}_{U}$ is the left ideal (or, equivalently, the
right ideal) generated by the elements $\nabla_{U}^{-}:=\sum\limits_{w\in
S_{U}}\left(  -1\right)  ^{w}w$ corresponding to all $\left(  k+1\right)
$-element subsets $U$ of $\left[  n\right]  $. Here, $S_{U}$ means the set of
all permutations $w\in S_{n}$ that fix all elements of $\left[  n\right]
\setminus U$.


Proofs of these are sketched in Section 2.7 (Proposition 2.7.1) of my draft
on rook sums in the symmetric group
algebra,
though I would not be surprised if the results are folklore. (The
$\nabla_{\mathbf{B},\mathbf{A}}$ have already been studied in E. R. Canfield,
S. G. Williamson, A combinatorial study of straightening bases,
1989, and later generalized to the
Hecke algebra by G. E. Murphy 1992.)
Now my question is:

Question. Let
\begin{align*}
H  &  =\left\{  \text{all hook-shaped partitions of }n\right\} \\
&  =\left\{  \left(  k,\underbrace{1,1,\ldots,1}_{n-k\text{ times}}\right)
\vdash n\ \mid\ k\in\left[  n\right]  \right\}
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
N  &  =\left\{  \text{all non-hook-shaped partitions of }n\right\} \\
&  =\left\{  \text{partitions of }n\right\}  \setminus H.
\end{align*}
Can we describe $\mathcal{A}_{H}$ (the "hook part" of $\mathcal{A}$) and
$\mathcal{A}_{N}$ (the "non-hook part")?

Using the hook length formula, it is easy to see that the dimension of
$\mathcal{A}_{H}$ as a $\mathbf{k}$-vector space is $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n
\dbinom{n-1}{k-1}^{2}=\dbinom{2n-2}{n-1}$. As a $\mathbf{k}$-algebra,
$\mathcal{A}_{H}$ is isomorphic to the planar rook algebra
$\mathcal{PR}_{n-1}\left(  \beta\right)  $ for any $\beta\neq0$ (see
§4.3 in Travis
Scrimshaw, Cellular subalgebras of the partition algebra,
arXiv:2211.08746v2), due to having a
direct product decomposition with the same factors. But how does
$\mathcal{A}_{H}$ look like inside $\mathcal{A}$? What is a generating or
spanning set?
EDIT: I have found nice descriptions of $\mathcal{A}_H$ and $\mathcal{A}_N$ in terms of Young-Jucys-Murphy elements. Namely, let $\mathbf{m}_{2,3,\ldots,n}$ be the sum of all $n$-cycles in $S_n$. (This is also the product of the $2$-nd, $3$-rd, ..., $n$-th Young-Jucys-Murphy elements in $\mathcal{A}$.) Then, $\mathcal{A}_H$ is the right ideal $\mathbf{m}_{2,3,\ldots,n} \mathcal{A}$ of $\mathcal{A}$, whereas $\mathcal{A}_N$ is the set of all $\mathbf{a} \in \mathcal{A}$ that satisfy $\mathbf{m}_{2,3,\ldots,n} \mathbf{a} = 0$. (Note that $\mathbf{m}_{2,3,\ldots,n}$ is a central element of $\mathcal{A}$, and thus we could put it on either side of the $\mathbf{a}$.) This is not hard to prove using the action of the Young-Jucys-Murphy elements on the seminormal basis.
Motivation. The above question has its origins in modular representation
theory, or in what little of it I understand. Indeed, the above decomposition
\eqref{eq.darij1.1} holds more generally when $\mathbf{k}$ is a field of any
characteristic $\notin\left\{  1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  $. But it breaks down if
$\operatorname*{char}\mathbf{k}\in\left\{  1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  $, since the
$\overline{\mathbf{E}}_{\lambda}$ are not even well-defined for these
$\mathbf{k}$'s as some of the hook length products $h^{\lambda}$ become $0$ in
$\mathbf{k}$. (One might try to "fix" this by removing the fractions from the
definitions of $\overline{\mathbf{E}}_{\lambda}$, but the linear disjointness
of the $\mathcal{A}\overline{\mathbf{E}}_{\lambda}$ cannot be salvaged.)
I am trying to understand what happens in the "critical" case when $n$ is a
prime number $p$, and when $\mathbf{k}$ is a field of characteristic $p$. In
this case, $h^{\lambda}=0$ in $\mathbf{k}$ if and only if $\lambda\in H$.
Thus, the "non-hook part" $\mathcal{A}_{N}$ of $\mathcal{A}$ still looks like
it does in characteristic $0$, in the sense that the idempotents
$\overline{\mathbf{E}}_{\lambda}$ for $\lambda\in N$ still exist and that
$\prod\limits_{\lambda\in N}\mathcal{A}\overline{\mathbf{E}}_{\lambda}$ is a
nonunital subalgebra of $\mathcal{A}$. This subalgebra has codimension
$\dbinom{2n-2}{n-1}$ in $\mathcal{A}$, which does not look like much compared
to $\dim\mathcal{A}=n!$. In a sense, this means that \eqref{eq.darij1.1} is
"mostly true" in this case. But to put some flesh on this intuition, I'd like
to understand what exactly is happening between $\prod\limits_{\lambda\in
N}\mathcal{A}\overline{\mathbf{E}}_{\lambda}$ and $\mathcal{A}$. For this, it
looks like a reasonable first step to understand $\mathcal{A}_{H}$ and
$\mathcal{A}_{N}$ in characteristic $0$, as above. Any prior work on this will
also be appreciated!
EDIT: Corollary 4.2.8 in Matthias Künzer, Ties for the integral group ring of the symmetric group, thesis appears to answer the motivating question about $n = p$.

You ask for a description of how $\mathcal{A}_H$ sits inside $\mathbf{k}[S_n]$. This wording suggests you wish to realise the first as a subalgebra of the second, but I will instead discuss it as a quotient. I am hopeful this will still be helpful/interesting to you. Of course, in characteristic zero, there is no difference due to the semisimplicity of the group algebra. Nevertheless I think that the quotient is the more natural formulation.
What I have to say is closely analogous to an example that you mention. So for the sake of clarity of exposition, I would like to discuss that example first.

Consider the algebra $A$ whose irreducible representations are Specht modules $S^\lambda$ indexed by partitions $\lambda \vdash n$ and at most two rows (it will turn out the be the Temperley-Lieb algebra $TL_n(2)$). It is certainly the case that the antisymmetriser $\varepsilon_3 = \sum_{w \in S_3} (-1)^{l(w)}w$ acts by zero on all such Specht modules. This is because their restriction from $S_n$ to $S_3$ cannot contain the sign representation (whose shape is $(1^3)$ and therefore not contained inside any two-row diagram). So $A$ is a quotient of $\mathbf{k}S_n / (\varepsilon_3)$. To see that actually $A = \mathbf{k}S_n / (\varepsilon_3)$, we must show that that $(\varepsilon_3)$ contains the matrix algebras of all $S^\lambda$ where $l(\lambda) \geq 3$. But any such $\lambda$ contains $(1^3)$ within its diagram, so the restriction of $S^\lambda$ to $S_3$ contains a copy of the sign representation, on which $\varepsilon_3$ acts non-trivially. Finally, observe that a matrix algebra is simple, so any non-zero element generates the full matrix algebra. (Incidentally, the elements $\nabla_U^-$ you mentioned are all conjugates of $\varepsilon_3$ by elements of $S_n$.)
Now to find a basis of $A$, observe that $(\varepsilon_3)$ is a span of elements of the form $g \varepsilon_3 h = gh (h^{-1}\varepsilon_3 h) = gh \nabla_U^-$, where $U = h^{-1}(\{1,2,3\})$. By reindexing $g$, we write this as $g \nabla_U^-$, which upon expanding is a linear relation among the 6 possible ways of modifying $g$ by permuting the values of $h^{-1}(\{1,2,3\})$. So whenever we see a permutation in $S_n$ with an occurence of the 321 permutation pattern, we may use this relation to rewrite it as a linear combination of the 5 permutations where the numbers forming the 321 pattern are permuted in a different way.
For example: (pardon my mixture of one-line and cycle notation) we may rewrite 4132 (where 432 is the 321 pattern occurrence) as
$$4132 = 2134 * (41) = 2134 * \left[(143) + (134) - (13) - (34) +\mathrm{Id} \right],$$
where the key point is that in each of the 5 terms on the right hand side, the three numbers at places 1,3,4 no longer form an occurrence of the pattern 321. Of course, 321 may appear as a pattern elsewhere, but we may apply the same logic to eliminate it in those places. At each step, the Coxeter length of the permutations decrease, so this process must terminate. With a little care, this turns into a proof of the fact that $A$ has a basis consisting of 321-avoiding permutations.
From a different direction, by Schur-Weyl duality,
$$(\mathbb{C}^2)^{\otimes n} = \bigoplus_{\lambda \vdash n, l(\lambda) \leq 2} S^{\lambda} \otimes V_{\lambda},$$
where $V_\lambda$ is the irreducible representation of $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$ (or $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$) indexed by $\lambda$. By double-centraliser theory, the $SL_2$-commutant of this, $\mathrm{End}_{SL_2}((\mathbb{C}^2)^{\otimes n})$, is precisely $A$. But this commutant is also the definition of the Temperley-Lieb algebra $TL_n(2)$.
Of course, the Temperley-Lieb algebra has some nice diagrammatic generators and relations, and the diagrammatic generators have a simple form in terms of the permutation realisation we have just discussed. It should also be mentioned that everything can be q-deformed, in which case we talk about Hecke algebras $H_n(q)$, quantum groups $U_q(sl_2)$, and $TL(q+q^{-1})$.

Now to discuss the algebra you ask about. Note that just as previously the set of partitions we excluded were those containing $(1^3)$, here we exclude those containing $(2^2)$. The same logic tells us that the algebra $\mathcal{A}_H$ is $\mathbb{k}[S_n]/(\epsilon)$, where
$$\epsilon = 2 \mathrm{Id} + 2\left[ (14)(23) + (13)(24) + (12)(34)\right] - \left[ (123) + (132) + (124) + (142) + (134) + (143) + (234) + (243)\right]$$
is (a scalar multiple of) the idempotent associated to the $S^{(2^2)}$. Note that it contains (14)(23) as a term, which is the longest element in $S_4$.
To produce a basis of this is a little trickier than the previous case. Note $S^{(2^2)}$ has a four dimensional endomorphism algebra which is spanned by the actions of $\mathrm{Id}, (12), (23), (123)$. This means that $\epsilon, (12)\epsilon, (23)\epsilon, (123)\epsilon$ should all act by zero.
We may use the relation coming from the quotient by $\epsilon$ to eliminate occurrences of $4321$ (in cycle notation (14)(23)).
Similarly, the relation from quotienting by $(12) \epsilon$ implies we may eliminate occurrences of $(12)(14)(23) = (1423) = 4312$ (again please excuse my mixing of one-line and cycle notations).
For $(23)\epsilon$ we may eliminate ocurrences of $(23)(14)(23) = (14) = 4231$.
Finally the case of $(123)\epsilon$ is a bit trickier. It contains (14)(23) which we have already eliminated, so really we should consider $(\mathrm{Id}+ 2(123))\epsilon$, which no longer contains $(14)(23)$. This element turns out to contain $(142) = 4132$, which we may eliminate.
I am brushing some details under the rug here: it is not the case that these eliminations strictly decrease Coxeter length in the appearing permutations. But one can define an different order: say that for $g_1, g_2$ in one-line notation, $g_1 > g_2$ if the largest number not in the same location is further on the left in $g_1$ than in $g_2$. The substitutions become strictly decreasing with respect to this ordering. The result is that this algebra has a basis consisting of permutations that avoid 4321, 4231, 4132, 4312. (But it is possible that I made a mistake.)
From the more abstract direction, tensor powers of $\mathbb{C}^2$, we may consider tensor power of the superspace $\mathbb{C}^{1|1}$. In this case the super-version of Schur-Weyl duality tells us that
$$(\mathbb{C}^{1|1})^{\otimes n} = \bigoplus_{0 \leq k \leq n/2} S^{(n-k, 1^k)} \otimes V_{(n-k,k)},$$
as a representation of $S_n \times GL_{1|1}(\mathbb{C})$. Double-centraliser theory again tells us that the $GL_{1|1}$-commutant of this, $\mathrm{End}_{GL_{1|1}}((\mathbb{C}^{1|1})^{\otimes n})$, is precisely $\mathcal{A}_H$. So the algebra you are after would naturally be called a "super-Temberley-Lieb algebra". However I am not aware of any work on this topic, the most I could find is mathoverflow question.

One other fact that might be of interest to you, is that the sum of $n$-cycles in $S_n$ acts by nonzero scalars on hooks, and by zero on non-hooks by the Murnaghan-Nakayama rule. So (at least over $\mathbb{C}$) $\mathcal{A}_H$ is generated by the sum of $n$-cycles.
I am a little worried that this is not really what you want, if it is your goal to understand modular representation theory. For one thing, over a field of positive characteristic, representations of quotients of $S_n$ might be a bit different from representations of $S_n$ itself. I am alluding to the fact that except for special cases, like the $n=p$ case for hooks, the set of irreducible representations $U$ is probably not a union of $p$-blocks, so the quotient does something nontrivial to the representation theory. Another concern, is that to reduce a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra modulo $p$, one chooses an integral form, and then reduces the integral form modulo $p$. This choice matters, so you had better be sure that the integral form you are working with is the one you want. For example, $\mathrm{Mat}_2(\mathbb{C})$ has $\mathrm{Mat}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ as an integral form, and also
$$\left\{ \begin{bmatrix}
    a & b\\
    c & d
  \end{bmatrix} \mid a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z}, p | c\right\}.$$
The mod-$p$ reduction of the first is obviously a matrix algebra, but for the second, one can check that the reduction modulo $p$ is not simple.

Very nice! I've just checked with SageMath that your permutation avoidance class has size $\dbinom{2n-2}{n-1}$ for all $n \leq 8$; this greatly improves the chances that you did things right. (Though some other classes have the same size, such as the slightly more memorable "avoid all $4$-patterns starting with a $4$ except for $4321$ and $4123$".) This actually makes me wonder if some Wilf equivalences can be explained by the invariance of the dimension applied to a quotient vector space of the symmetric group algebra, with two different confluent rewrite rules.

And yeah, my mod-$p$ motivation seems to be unrelated to the actual question, and is quasi-answered in Künzer's thesis anyway (see my EDIT).

My brief comment about the partial order was misleading, and I have corrected my original post. I agree it would be interesting to exhibit Wilf equivalence by finding two different rewriting rules, but after some thought I was not able to come up with alternative that lead to a non-trivial Wilf equivalence.
